# Connect to Database on local host with sqlite3 in python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, database, sqlite

I have a database that I am running on my local machine which I can access through Microsoft SQL Server Manager Studio. I connect to this server "JIMS-LAPTOP\SQLEXPRESS" and then I can run queries through the manager. However I need to be able to connect to this database and work with it through python. 
When I try to connect using sqlite3 like

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("JIMS-LAPTOP\SQLEXPRESS")
```

I get an unable to open database file error

I tried accessing the temporary file directly like this

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("C:\Users\Jim Notaro\AppData\Local\Temp\~vs13A7.sql")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = \"table\"")
print c.fetchall()
```

Which allows me to access a database but it is completely empty (No tables are displayed)

I also tried connecting like this

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("SQL SERVER (SQLEXPRESS)")
```

Which is what the name is in the sql server configuration manager but that also returns a blank database.

I'm not sure how I am suppose to be connecting to the database using python

Answer (score 1):

You can't use sqlite3 to connect to SQL server, only to Sqlite databases.
You need to use a driver that can talk to MS SQL, like `pyodbc`.

Comment: My end goal is to use an ORM like sqlalchemy to work with the database. Is it possible to connect to an sql server with that. And if so how would I do that

Comment: SqlAlchemy has good docs, you should spend some time with them.  An example of a SA connection string I used to connect to SQL server is `mssql+pyodbc://server/dbname?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0`